# Interpreting matrix notation to run MLE in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, matrix

I am trying to re-create some indicators from the World Bank, using the methodology described in [this](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1682130) paper, and I need to do maximum likelihood estimation, preferably using R.

The aim is to get an overall (unobserved) indicator from many different (observed) scores.  My data looks like this:

```
   Country   Score Source
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1 Albania   0.6   EIU   
 2 Albania   0.797 GCS   
 3 Albania   0.833 WMO   
 4 Albania   0.756 PRS   
 5 Algeria   0.45  EIU   
 6 Algeria   0.739 GCS   
 7 Algeria   0.5   WMO   
 8 Algeria   0.634 PRS   
 9 Argentina 0.65  EIU   
10 Argentina 0.725 GCS   
11 Argentina 0.75  WMO   
12 Argentina 0.795 PRS
```

Based on the formulas and variables given in the paper, I am estimating the following model:

$y_j{_k} = \alpha_k + \beta_k(g_j + \varepsilon_j{_k})$

Where $y{_j}{_k}$ is the observed score of country $j$ from source $k$.  This observed score is a linear function of an unobserved indicator, $g_j$, for each country $j$ and a disturbance term, $\varepsilon_j{_k}$, where $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ are parameters which map the unobserved indicator in country $j$, $g_j$ into the observed data $y_j{_k}$.  $g_j$ is assumed to be a normally-distributed random variable with mean zero and variance one.  We also assume the error term is normally distributed, with zero mean and a variance that is the same across countries, but differs across indicators, i.e. $V[\varepsilon_j{_k}] = \sigma_k^{2}$.  We also assume that the errors are independent across sources, i.e., $E[\varepsilon_j{_k}\varepsilon_j{_m}] = 0$ for source $m$ different from source $k$.

I want to estimate the parameters $\alpha_k$, $\beta_k$, and $\sigma_k^2$ for every data source $k$, using maximum likelihood.  The paper I referenced says that the contribution to the log-likelihood of country $j$ is given by:

$ln L(\alpha, \beta, \sigma^2) \propto ln|\Omega| + (y_j - \alpha)'\Omega^{-1}(y_j-\alpha)$

Where $\alpha = \Big(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_K{_j}\Big)$, $\beta = \Big(\beta_1, ..., \beta_K{_j}\Big)$, and $\sigma^2 = \Big(\sigma^2_1, ..., \sigma^2_K{_j}\Big)$, and $B$ and $\Sigma$ are diagonal matrices with $\alpha$ and $\sigma^2$ on the diagonal.  Furthermore, the mean of the vector of observed data for each country $j$, $y_j$, is $\alpha$ and the variance is $\Omega = \beta\beta' + B\Sigma B'$.  Summing over all countries $j$ and then maximizing over the unknown parameters should give the maximum-likelihood estimates of $\alpha_k$, $\beta_k$, and $\sigma^2_k$ for every data source $k$.

There are a couple of things that confuse me about this notation:

- are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma^2$ matrices or vectors?  The paper gives them inside of big parens, which I take to be matrix notation.  But they only have one dimension, so are they $1$ X $k$, or $k$ X $k$, with $\alpha ... \alpha_K{_j}$ as the diagonal?
- why are we taking transposes of diagonal matrices (like $B$)?
- why are there pipes around the log of omega, i.e., $ln|\Omega|$ instead of parens, i.e., $ln(\Omega)$

So, most of the resources I can find for calculating MLE in R are based on pretty simple examples, where you estimate only a few parameters.  In this case, I want to estimate whole matrices of parameters, so I am a little unclear on how to do that.  Moreover, we are taking the formula given and summing it across every country.

The best attempt I have so far looks like this (where `dat` is the dataframe with my data):

```
nll <- function(alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4, beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, sigma4){
  alpha <- diag(c(alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4))
  beta <- diag(c(beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4))
  sigma <- diag(c(sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, sigma4))

  LL <- 0
  for (country in unique(dat$Country)){
    ix <- dat$Country == country

    y <- dat$Score[ix]

    omega <- beta*t(beta) + alpha*sigma*t(alpha)

    LL <- LL + log(omega) + t(y - alpha)*omega^-1*(y - alpha)
  }
  LL
}


stats4::mle(minuslogl = nll, start = list(alpha1=0.5, alpha2=0.5, alpha3=0.5, alpha4=0.5, 
                                          beta1=1, beta2=1, beta3=1, beta4=1, 
                                          sigma1=1, sigma2=1, sigma3=1, sigma4=1))
```

However, this throws an error when I try to run the estimation.  I also dont think I should be hardcoding a separate alpha, beta, and sigma for each score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. "Are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma^2$ matrices or vectors? The paper gives them inside of big parens, which I take to be matrix notation. But they only have one dimension, so are they $1 \times K$, or $K \times K$, with $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{Kj}$ as the diagonal?"**

A vector is just a matrix with a single column, so it doesn't really matter what you call $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma^2$, so long as the are used in conformable ways with other matrices or vectors.  Sometimes authors write vectors on a single line in the body of text to save space, but they will usually write them as transposed to make it clear they are vectors (e.g. $X^\prime=(x_1,...,x_k)$, but this isn't always the case and some authors get a little sloppy and forget to write the transpose sign, writing a vector as just $X=(x_1,...,x_k)$ in the body text.  Often the reader must use context clues and conformability checks to determine how they are treated.  In this case, you should consider $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma^2$ as vectors (of dimensions $K_j\times 1$) because later in the text, the author states that the $B$ and $\Sigma$ are diagonal matrices with $\alpha$ and $\sigma^2$ on the diagonals (which implies $B$ and $\Sigma$ themselves are $K_j\times K_j$) and adds $\beta\beta^\prime$ to $B{\Sigma}B^\prime$ and the only way that would be conformable is if $\beta$ where a vector.

*Note*:  your question asked if the vectors have a dimension of $K$.  You should be careful to note that none of these have a $K$ dimension, but they have a $K_j$ dimension (the rows dimension).  This is important because $K$ changes from country to country, so in the $j$th country, each of these vectors would be of length $K_j$.  So in one country $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma^2$ might be of length 10 (i.e. $K_j=10$).  In another, they might be of length 15 (i.e. $K_j=15$).

**2. "Why are we taking transposes of diagonal matrices (like $B$)?"**

Transposes are taken on matrices or vectors in order to make them conformable with other matrices and/or vectors to obtain a desired result.  In the referenced paper, the transpose is taken on $B$ in order to square the $a_1, a_2,...,a_{K_{j}}$ terms on the diagonal.  To see this, note that, as described in the text, $B$, looks like this:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{K_{j}}
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

So, $BB^{\prime}$ will look like this:

\begin{eqnarray*}
BB^{\prime} & = & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{K_{j}}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{K_{j}}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1}^{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{2}^{2} & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{K_{j}}^{2}
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

At one point in text you see $B{\Sigma} B^\prime$.  This is doing the same thing as above, only adding the $\sigma_j$ terms on the diagonal since $\Sigma$ is diagonal.  In another place in the paper, the vector $\beta$ is transposed and premultiplied by $\beta$.  This is done to create a $K_j\times K_j$ matrix with the squared $\beta_j$ terms on the diagonal and the $\beta_j \beta_k$ terms on the off diagonals where $i\ne k$ .

**3. "why are there pipes around the log of omega, i.e., $ln|\Omega|$ instead of parens, i.e., $ln(\Omega)$"**

In mathematical notation, two vertical bars around a matrix like $\Omega$ indicates that the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the matrix argument should be taken.  So, in this case $|\Omega|$ means that the determinant of $\Omega$.  This is also sometimes written $det(\Omega)$.

Now that you know the answers to 1, 2, and 3 above, I'd suggest, you try to revisit your R code.  If you still cannot get your R code to work, I would suggest you accept this answer (if it's helpful) and then post a totally *separate* question regarding any problems you run into with R.  As an aside, I would recommend you consult with a statistician on this.  From a very cursory review of the paper you referenced (I didn't read the whole paper, of course), it looks like the authors are building their model using linear mixed effects models.  I think this is the case since I saw terms like $\Omega=\beta \beta^\prime + B\Sigma B$ on page 24 and this type of equation usually pops up in linear mixed effects models.  This is important, because if this is the case, you don't need to re-invent the wheel with your R code and computer anything manually.  Instead, you could probably invoke the appropriate mixed model commands (e.g. those found in the pages like `lme4`, `nlme`) after simply reading in your data, and the program will compute everything for you - so probably no need to write that big ugly function you seem to be working on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @StatsStudent.  Your response to #3 and your suggestion to look into mixed models definitely help.  I'm still confused about the transposes though.  For part 1, if $\beta$ is a $1$X$K_j$ matrix, how can I take $\beta\beta'$?  Wouldnt they be non conformable (ie, one is $1$X$K_j$ and one is $K_j$X$1$)?  Also, for part 2, how is $BB'$ different from just $BB$ (without transposing the second $B$)?  Aren't they identical?

Comment: No problem.  No, if you are considering $\beta$ a matrix, then it is $K_j\times 1$ not vice versa.  I think you are better off calling it "vector" (although technically either is right, but usually what we call $N\times 1$ structures a vector).  So then $\beta \beta^\prime$ is conformable.  When you post-multiply a $K_j\times 1$ vector by a $1 \times K_j$ (transposed) vector the result is a $K_j\times K_j$ matrix.  In part two, $BB=BB^\prime$ in this particular case since $B$ is diagonal.  This is not generally always the case though.